# UIImage initWithCGImage leads to memory issue in Obj-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I develop an application that grabs images from iPhone rear camera. These images are then processed asynchronously.

So I am using **AVFoundation** functions in **Obj-C**. My problem is that my app is crashing because of memory issue when capturing images.

Here is the code that I use in the **captureOutput** callback :

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)output didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft;
    CVPixelBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    CIImage* ciimage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCVPixelBuffer:imageBuffer];
    CIContext* context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImage* cgImage = [context createCGImage:ciimage fromRect:[ciimage extent]];

    @synchronized(self) {
        UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage];
        self.uiimageBuffer = image;
    }
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);
}
```

As I need to asynchronously process the image grabbed elsewhere in the application, I introduced a buffer called **uiimageBuffer**. This buffer is updated everytime captureOutput is called, like written right below :

```
UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage];
self.uiimageBuffer = image;
```

But the allocation of the UIImage leads to **memory issue** very very quickly (few seconds).

So **my question** is : how could I update my buffer without allocating new UIImage at every calls of captureOutput ?

**PS** : the same piece of code written in Swift 4 doesn't lead to memory issue.

Thank you

Comment: So, your first problem is the call CIContext* context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil], don't do that on every loop as the Core Image context is a ref you should hold on to from one call to the next. This change will significantly improve performance and avoid allocations on every invocation. Also, can you just use the CoreImage CIImage ref created with the pixel buffer and then make a UIImage from that? This will also avoid an allocation as it would just read from the original source.

Comment: Also, do you need to release the incoming CMSampleBufferRef here? If it leaks then your app will run out of memory right away since CoreVideo buffers are huge.

Comment: Is this compiled under ARC?

Comment: @Sulthan it is compiled under ARC

Comment: @MoDJ using context outside of the loop gives better results but still crashing. If comment the two lines : UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage];
self.uiimageBuffer = image; there is no memory issue but the buffer isn't updated

Comment: Do you need a CFRelease(sampleBuffer) in your code? I don't know what is calling this method so I cannot be sure.

Comment: you should resize image until it is small. then you wont have memory issue. your code take full HD size which the iphone memory cannot handle.

Answer (score 0):

How about @autoreleasepool? This helped me several times in both captureOutput and requestMediaDataWhenReady.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html